# ASP.net MVC Core and IdentityServer 4: Setting defaultScheme in AddAuthentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, access-token, identityserver4

I am looking at the code below. The AddAuthentication added defaultScheme with "Cookies". Does this mean the current mvc application only accept Cookie authentication but not Access Token by default.

```
services.AddOptions();
//services.Configure(Configuration);
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
services.AddSession();

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
```

Currently, I wanted to have access one single page with my mobile application which authenticated with it's access token which logged in from the app itself. 
I wonder how do I request the webpage inside my webview by using AccessToken instead of Cookie.

There is something called Authorize attribute with difference acceptable scheme I can pass in. I wonder is this the way to set it up.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

That is for Accesstoken only, if I need both I add cookie as well

Comment: You will need to use `AddJwtBearer(options => { ... });` to your authentication methods to use access tokens.

Comment: Does this affect all the page to be accessible with access token?

Answer (score 2):

```
options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
```

This means that the authentication scheme, if not specified otherwise, will be `"Cookies"`.

```
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
```

This means that the default challenge authentication scheme, if not specified otherwise, will be `"oidc"`.

This is how the OIDC and Cookie authentication schemes will usually work with each other: The application will attempt to authenticate the user using the existing cookie. If that fails (because there’s no cookie), then an authentication challenge will be made using the OIDC scheme. This will then relay the authentication to the external provider, and when that succeeds, the OIDC scheme will sign the user in using the Cookie authentication scheme. This creates the cookie, so on the next request, the cookie authentication scheme will be able to authenticate the user (without having to ask the OIDC scheme again).

If you want other authentication schemes to work, then you will have to add those too. `AddAuthentication(…).AddCookie(…).AddOpenIdConnect(…)` will just set this chain up. If you also want a JWT bearer authentication, you need to configure that as well.

But just because you `.AddJwtBearer(…)` that does not mean that anything about the normal flow will change: The Cookie scheme will still be the default, and the OIDC scheme will still be the default challenge. As I said above: Unless you specify otherwise.

So when you want to authorize the user using JWT Bearer authentication, you will need to trigger that explicitly. As you have noticed yourself, this can be done using the `Authorize` attribute. But in order for that to work, you will still have to set up the JWT Bearer authentication properly. But then it can work in parallel to the already set up Cookie/OIDC setup.

Comment: I am very new to this.. Is there a simple setup to look at?

Comment: You can follow any JWT Bearer authentication tutorial for ASP.NET Core here. For example [this one](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/).